# Byte size not increasing in a dynamic array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

```
import ctypes
import sys

class DynamicArray(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 
        self.capacity = 1 
        self.A = self.make_array(self.capacity)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n

    def __getitem__(self,k):
        if not 0 <= k <self.n:
            return IndexError('K is out of bounds!')

        return self.A[k] 

    def append(self, ele):
        if self.n == self.capacity:
            self._resize(2*self.capacity) 

        self.A[self.n] = ele 
        self.n += 1

    def _resize(self,new_cap):
        B = self.make_array(new_cap)

        for k in range(self.n):
            B[k] = self.A[k]

        self.A = B 
        self.capacity = new_cap 

    def make_array(self,new_cap):
        return (new_cap * ctypes.py_object)()
```

When I use

```
arr = DynamicArray()
```

and after inserting about 10 to 20 numbers the byte size remains the same.

This is how I check the size of the array:

```
sys.getsizeof(arr)
```

The byte size shows to be 56 throughout.

Comment: Why do you think `sys.getsizeof` should return a different value? Have you *read the documentation for this function?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as it returns the size of an object in bytes

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what it is doing. Did you read the documentation? Again, **why** did you expect the size to change?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as im increasing the items in the array shoudnt its size increase too? im sorry im new to this am i missing something here?. As list is a dynamic array itself when i increase the size of the array by appending integers. Shoudnt its size in bytes also increase.
and yes i read the documentation it gives the byte size of an object.

Comment: No, **did you read the documentation or not**? Note, you `DynamicArray ` object doesn't actually contain any of the items itself..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, so how do i check the byte size of the Dynamic Array?

Comment: Exactly the way you are doing it. For the last time **have you read the documentation or not**?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have read the Documentation Bud.
Correct me if i am wrong?
As i am appending items in the array?
I think the the size of the array in bytes should also increase?
am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Did you read the part where it states "Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." Your object doesn't actually contain any items, instead, it references a `ctypes` object which is actually the underlying array (well, a wrapper around a primitive buffer, but whatever). And also a link to a recursive implementation which gets the size of the object and all the objects it holds references to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Im  sorry no i didnt there was nothing as such where i read it

Comment: Then you were *not* reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 
https://github.com/jmportilla/Python-for-Algorithms--Data-Structures--and-Interviews/blob/master/Array%20Sequences/Dynamic%20Array%20Exercise.ipynb

read at the end and please tell me what is he asking for then?
im confused

Comment: What is confusing? I guess he's asking you to play around with it. I don't know what that person is intending, it is probably a better question for them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and also then where are the integers getting stored then? and wherever they are How do i calculate the size of that list/array/whatever it is??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay so u are saying the size will not increase or decrease while using it? Right?

Comment: **You've just shown this yourself**. Why are you asking *me*? I've already explained to you *why* and shown you the documentation.

Comment: Your array only holds references to things. Each of those references costs a machine word (probably 8 bytes). I already explained, you are using a `ctypes` array to actually store things. Of course, it is of type `PyObject`, so it too will only hold references. The actual python objects it is referring to will exist on the privately managed heap of the CPython runtime. Note, getting the size of ctypes objects also requires care.

Comment: Okay, so my problem was  as the tutor said *see how it resizes..*  and the size was not increasing that was why i was asking you the question. Anyway thank you so much